# How to get one form value to another form value in php

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form  which looks like this:
[image: Device Ip]
[image: Connect Device Button]

```
<form name = "infoDominio" action="<?php echo htmlentities('ip_connect.php');?>"method="get">
  <div class="form-group">
     <div class="param2">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Device Ip:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-2">                           
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="get_url_1" value="192"/></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">                            
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="get_url_2" value="168"/></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">                            
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="get_url_3" value="27"/></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">                            
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="get_url_4" value="123"/></div>
     </div>
     <div class="param1">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">                 
            <div class="col-sm-6">                       
                <input  name="infoDominio" type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Connect Device"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>  
   </div>
</form>
```

Device ip and Connect Device are in the same form. Now my Problem is my Button has another form. When I press this button I get the value from the form infoDominio four block IP value.

```
<form name="get_card" action="<?php echo htmlentities('get_device_card.php');?>" method="get">
   <input  name="infoDominio" type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm" value="Get Device Card">
</form>
```

[image: get_device_card]

Comment: What value you want from one form to another form?

Comment: you'll need some (simple) javascript for that.

Comment: 192 168 27 123 these four values I want from infoDominio form to get_card form @Nayak

Comment: But how I get @Jeff

Comment: use some search and you'll find plenty of examples like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078460/submit-form-with-a-new-value-using-javascript-mvc